# How do I make CoreData models conform to a protocol?

Tags: swift, core-data, protocols, swift-protocols

I'm trying to make a persistence framework-agnostic codebase.  i.e. I want protocol-oriented programming, but I'm having trouble making that work with CoreData.

Say I have a protocol:

```
public protocol BookItem {
  var title: String { get }
  var filename: String { get }
  var createdAt: Date { get }
  var content: BookItemContent? { get }
}
```

and another protocol

```
public protocol BookItemContent {
  var bookItem: BookItem { get }
  var data: Data { get }
}
```

When I make concrete types in CoreData, I might have:

```
class CDBookItem: NSManagedObject, BookItem {

  @NSManaged public var title: String?
  @NSManaged public var filename: String?
  @NSManaged public var createdAt: NSDate?
  @NSManaged public var content: CDBookItemContent?
}

class CDBookItemContent: NSManagedObject, BookItemContent {

  @NSManaged public var data: NSData?
  @NSManaged public var bookItem: CDBookItem?
}
```

I have 3 issues here:

1)  Now I have multiple properties with different return types. (e.g. the `.content` property)

How do I best solve this?  The worst and dirty way is to rename all the Core-Data attributes, then wrap them to conform.

The other way I can see is to manually generate the NSManagedObject subclasses, then change the flavour that the CoreData codegen is creating, so to remove the optionality.  Still, then I'm left with `content: BookItemContent` and `content: CDBookItemContent`, so I don't know if there's an elegant way to do what I'm hoping to do here.  I was hoping I could just declare that the NSManagedObject subclass conforms to its intended protocol type and the compiler figures this out.

2)  Core Data codegen uses 'NSObject' types, instead of their modern equivalent.  (i.e. NSData and not Data, NSDate and not Date).  Can I just modify the codegen files to remove the "NS" and get free bridging?

3)  Is it known that CoreData always creates optional object properties in the codegen, even if you don't want them to be?  Is the solution literally to overwrite the manually generated files?

Comment: Don't fight the framework.  Protocol-oriented programming for ***classes*** which are subclassed heavily is discouraged. If you want to change the default behavior of Core Data codgen don't use it. Create the `NSManagedObject` subclasses manually with the `Editor` menu item and modify the files (replace the `NS...` classes with Swift types and declare the needed properties as non-optional)

Comment: I have something similar but for properties like your `content` I implemented get/set methods in an extension to conform to the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I'm finding Protocol-oriented Programming is not exactly as promised.  I was hoping almost an entire codebase could be done in this way.  In the end the solution was to make NSManagedObject subclasses conform to a protocol by having to explicitly write accessors for the protocol's properties that wrap some attribute on the core data model.  i.e. `return myManagedObject.contentObject as! BookItemContent`